# Why aren't ajax calls being made with a specified delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call an action on a controller with ajax: 10 times with a 2 second delay in my MVC5 application.

Here is the code I've written:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    (function loop(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var d = new Date();
            console.log(d.getTime());
            callAjax();
                console.log("works " + i);
                if (--i) loop(i); 
            },
            2000); // ms
    })(10);

    function callAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/StartElection',
            type: 'POST',
            data: "test",
            async: true
        })
            .done(function (partialViewResult) {
                $("#partialTable").html(partialViewResult);
            });
    };
});
```

> The console log is as expected (with a 2 second delay) but the calls to the controller happen instantly - when I set a break in Visual Studio on the controller action the next call after continuing takes 2ms

I can't see why this is happening - can any one help?

**Edit:** I added a console log of Date.getTime() just before the ajax call & there are 2000 ms between each

Comment: How do you check it?

Comment: I've got a breakpoint on the action being called & as soon as I continue it hits the breakpoint again

Comment: I guess your observation is wrong due to async nature of ajax call. Instead  of using blocking statement as breakpoint, check your network tab to see request send. EDIT:  you mean breakpoint server side or client side?

Comment: Hmm, your code is working for me https://jsfiddle.net/j8eouz1w/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm setting a breakpoint in Visual Studio on the controller action

Comment: @NRKirby Ok i don't know enough VS IDE and breakpoint statement but for sure nothing is wrong in your client side posted code.  The thing is that ajax is async and your code client side doesn't wait for any ajax response before next loop iteration

Comment: If you were calling `loop(i)` from ajax done callback, you would't get fooled

Comment: @A.Wolff Can you be more specific & write what I should try?

Comment: @NRKirby Your code should be something like that e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/j8eouz1w/3/  This way if any of your ajax request takes more than 2 sec to complete, it won't send any parallel request if any previous one still running. See some reading: http://reallifejs.com/brainchunks/repeated-events-timeout-or-interval/

Comment: @A.Wolff the code in the fiddle worked with a little adaptation - care to do an answer & I will accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this line alone async: true -> async: false
because the AJAX calls will be made asynchronous if this property is set to true.
And so your ajax calls have no time delay.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your client side code is concerned it seems to be working well as far as calls are concerned. With that said here are a few things to consider when dealing with ajax:

1) You have control over the number of times that you can call a remote service but you have no control over the time it will take for that service to respond.

2) As such it is usual good practise for most cases to not make ajax calls in a loop (this somewhat defeats the general purpose of ajax). Rather use the response to each call to then make the next call (but then of course we would need to know exactly what it is you are trying to build to suggest an exact solution).

So the closest thing to what you are looking for using ajax I think would be more of something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    /*(function loop(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var d = new Date();
            console.log(d.getTime());
            callAjax();
                console.log("works " + i);
                if (--i) loop(i); 
            },
            2000); // ms
    })(10);*/

    var i=0;
    function callAjax() {
        var requestTimeMessage = "fetch #"+i+" at: "+new Date().getTime();
        console.log(requestMessage);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/StartElection',
            type: 'POST',
            data: "test",
            async: true
        })
            .done(function (partialViewResult) {
                var requestTimeMessage = "response #"+i+" at: "+new Date().getTime();
                console.log(requestMessage);

                $("#partialTable").html(partialViewResult);
                i++;
                if(i<10) {
                    /*Note this assumes a quick response for each call.
                    * Otherwise the response together with this delay will total a wait longer than 2 seconds.
                    */
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        callAjax();
                    2000);
                }
            });
    };
});
```

But as I said. I would need to know exactly what you are trying to achieve to give more appropriate answer to your question.